# Apply a Word32 function to a ByteString

Tags: haskell

I have a ByteString `b` with a length of the form 4*n (with integer n) and want to use `map` with a function `f::Word32->Word32` on `b` (so that `f` gets applied to "`b[0..3]`", "`b[4..7]`", etc). How can this be done in an efficient (and elegant) way?

Comment: Is your data is binary or human readable? Should the 4 byte bytestring `0x31343239` get interpreted as `1429`, `9241` or as binary `Word32` 825,504,313?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *chunk up* the `ByteString` very efficiently, given that [`B.take`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:take) and [`B.drop`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:drop) are both `O(1)` operations:

```
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

chunk :: Int -> ByteString -> [ByteString]
chunk k = takeWhile (not . B.null) . map (B.take k) . iterate (B.drop k)
```

then:

```
\> :set -XOverloadedStrings
\> chunk 4 "abcdefghijkl"
["abcd","efgh","ijkl"]
```

the rest would be to map over the list converting to and from desired type, and a single call to [`B.concat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:concat) at the end.

A possible `fromByteString` could be implemented using bit shifts and left fold:

```
import Data.Bits (Bits, shiftL, (.|.))

fromByteString :: (Num a, Bits a) => ByteString -> a
fromByteString = B.foldl go 0
    where go acc i = (acc  `shiftL` 8) .|. (fromIntegral i)
```

then:

```
\> map fromByteString $ chunk 4 "abcdefghijkl" :: [Word32]
[1633837924,1701209960,1768581996]
```

Comment: I'm not really sure whether `ByteString.Conversion` does the right thing. It parses the numbers as `Char8` with attoparsec.

Comment: If the ultimate goal is something of type `ByteString -> ByteString`, won't the reassembly step from 4-byte chunks kill the performance?

Answer (score 4):

A hackish but efficient way is to [convert to a storable vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/spool-0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Storable-ByteString.html) (which does not require a copy!), map over that, and convert back:

```
import Data.Vector.Storable.ByteString
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as VS
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

mapBSChunks :: (VS.Storable a, VS.Storable b)
              => (a->b) -> BS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString
mapBSChunks f = vectorToByteString . VS.map f . byteStringToVector
```

As per [Michael's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611414/apply-a-word32-function-to-a-bytestring/35612381?noredirect=1#comment58939889_35612381), you can easily define those hackish conversion functions locally:

```
bytestringToVector bs = runST
   ( V.unsafeThaw (toByteVector bs) >>= V.unsafeFreeze . M.unsafeCast )
vectorToByteString v = runST
   ( V.unsafeThaw v >>= fmap fromByteVector . V.unsafeFreeze . M.unsafeCast )
```

though I'd rather depend on a library to provide this, *in particular* because the unsafe casting is a bit fishy.

Comment: *"Depending on this library should be seen as a way to document and standardize an existing hack, and not as an absolute guarantee of correct behavior. "* Given that the library is from 2011 and does not have a version in Stack's LTS, is it still working as intended?

Comment: I had my doubts too, but it does seem to work fine. Perhaps somebody should port those conversions to a well-maintained package.

Comment: I think monotraversable's [`Data.ByteVector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.10.1/docs/Data-ByteVector.html ) is the most visible thing like this - at least when taken together with [`unsafeCast`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/src/Data-Vector-Storable-Mutable.html#unsafeCast) Maybe monotraversable could do with a few more functions like this.

Comment: also _"This function can produce Vectors which do not obey architectural alignment requirements."_ which is what I was wondering about

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Well, neither `ForeignPtr` leaks. As long as there is nothing in `vector` or `bytestring` that modifies the `ForeignPtr` of a non-mutable object it should be fine. How did you find this? Hayoo or hoogle?

Comment: @Zeta: hm, I know little about the internals of either vector or bytestring; makes me rather a bit uneasy thinking that vector might cause trouble by doing some clever re-allocations! This `spool` package I found through Google, strangely enough.

Comment: In terms of standard library functions, then, these are `bytestringToVector bs = runST (V.unsafeThaw (toByteVector bs) >>= V.unsafeFreeze . M.unsafeCast)` and
`vectorToByteString v =  runST (V.unsafeThaw v >>= fmap fromByteVector . V.unsafeFreeze . M.unsafeCast )`